# Can I use 2 receiver decorators on a django signal?

Tags: python-3.x, signals, django-1.7

Is it possible to make this signal also trigger on superuser creation using a decorator?

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def checkin_added(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Settings.objects.create(user=instance)
```